# Managing Fragmented Memory to provide Vector like functionality

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

This is one of the questions i was asked in one of the interviews, seeking possible approach for the solution.

We have a total of 1500 bytes memory available in block sizes of 100 bytes, 200 bytes, 300 bytes, 400 bytes, 500 bytes all scattered in the available memory area i.e. these block of bytes are not contiguous. How will we provide a vector like functionality to the user. Vector functionality means adding/deleting/inserting/accessing data of the vector. How will the memory allocation be handled for all such operations.

Looking for some approaches on the same.

Comment: Well you can't provide more than 500 bytes of storage in a single vector, since vector's storage is required to be contiguous.

Comment: Check out linked list C-style

Comment: what about `std::list` which is usually implemented as a `doubly-linked list`

Comment: I would go with a linked-list type of data structure, you can't do it with array as they require contiguous memory, however a list type of data structure may not be able to provide every functionality of array/vector such as indexed base searching etc, but definitely basic functionalities can be implemented.

Comment: You could also do things like use the contiguous patches as arrays and then have an additional patch with indexing, so that you can do binary search when looking up an element using its index. That reduces the complexity of index-based lookup to O(log H) (with H the number of patches), which may be better than O(H) (not in this scenario though, probably, due to number of elements). Think of it as a linked list of arrays. Even without the binary search index, you still get better performance, both memory and performance as you only need forward/reverse pointers for patches, not for elements.

Comment: Sounds like [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)